# Hibernate selecting queries in Java

Tags: java, sql, spring, string, hibernate

I'm attempting to use Jackson/Hibernate/SQL/Java to carry out select.

Here is what I am trying:

```
 Transaction tx = null;
    List<Note> list = null;

    try {
        tx = dbSession.beginTransaction();
        Query query = dbSession.createQuery("select Note from notes where name= :nameQ and university= :universityQ " +
                "and professor= :professorQ");
        query.setParameter("nameQ", "ONE");
        query.setParameter("universityQ", "TWO");
        list = query.list();
        tx.commit();
        return new FileInfo(Integer.toString(list.size()), fileName);
    }
```

But I am getting a nullptr exception, which obviously means something is wrong in the query. What is wrong with this? The note class is:

```
@Table(name="notes")
@Entity
public class Note {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="course")
    private String course;

    @Column(name="university")
    private String university;

    @Column(name="date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name="professor")
    private String professor;

    @Column(name="semester")
    private String semester;

    @Column(name="url")
    private String url;

    public Note(){

    }

    public Note(String name, String course, String university, String date, String professor, String semester) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
        this.university = university;
        this.date = date;
        this.professor = professor;
        this.semester = semester;
    }

  //Usual setters/getters
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Are you deliberately not setting the 'professorQ' parameter?

Comment: @khriskooper wow, not sure how I missed that.. I'll get back to you

Comment: general syntax is "select n from Note n where ..."

Answer (score 2):

Look at your query. You work with 3 different parameters `nameQ`, `universityQ` and `professorQ` however you set only 2 of them. Try to add the following line to set the missing parameter and avoid the NullPointerException.

```
query.setParameter("professorQ", "THREE");
```

---

Moreover you `select Note` that is incorrect. The correct HQL query is:

```
from notes where name= :nameQ and university= :universityQ and professor= :professorQ"
```

This helps you to get the whole row(s) with all the columns.

Comment: Should there be no "select" or anything?

Comment: Nope. There is a difference between SQL and HQL.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things, which I noticed :

1. You haven't defined `Note` column in `Note` class. But, you are querying it

   ```
    "select Note from notes
   ```

I think, you probably need to change above query to

```
   "from notes
```

2. You aren't setting `:professorQ`

   ```
   "and professor= :professorQ");
   ```

Comment: how can I query the note objects then? I know its not a column, but I want the object itself?

Comment: look at my updated solution. `Note` class define all your columns, means you need to select all column

Comment: So should the next step be `List<Note> list = query.list();`?  Im still getting nullpointer

Comment: if you are getting nullpointer at mentioned line means query is null. Otherwise point the exact line where you are getting exception